# Consulta de datos MySQL no me funciona cuando envio varias opciones en mi etiqueta SELECT de html

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, sql, html-select

Estoy consultando datos con **php, html, mysql**,
tengo una etiqueta **select** y me funciona cuando solo seleciono un dato pero cuando le agrego la funcionalidad a esa etiqueda **select** de que se pueda elegir varias opciones me falla la consulta y no me trae nada de datos aunque si existan,
Adjunto el código de la etiqueta **SELECT** con el atributo **MULTIPLE**

```html
<select data-placeholder="Selecione clientes" id="show_product" multiple class="chosen-select row">
     <?php echo fill_product($connect);?>  
</select>
```

Con el siguiente código **AJAX** voy a tomar los datos de esos input para mandarlos a mi archivo php que busca los datos en la base de datos:

```html
      $('#filter').click(function(){  
        from_date = $('#from_date').val();
        to_date = $('#to_date').val();
        codper = $('#brand').val();
        codcli = $('#show_product').val();
        console.log(codcli);
        //console.log(codcli, from_date, to_date);
        if(codper != "" && codcli != "" && from_date != '' && to_date != '')  {  
             $.ajax({  
                  url:"user_data.php",  
                  method:"POST",  
                  data:{codper:codper, codcli:codcli, from_date:from_date, to_date:to_date},
                  beforeSend: function() {
                    $('#order_table').css('background', 'url(/img/ajaxloader.gif) no-repeat center top')
                  },
                  complete: function(){
                    $('#order_table').css('background', 'none')
                  },
                  success:function(data)  
                  {  
                       $('#order_table').html(data);  
                  }  
             });  
        } else{  
             alert("Selecione agencia, usuario y rango de fechas");  
        }  
     });
```

Este es mi código **php** donde reviso que no vengan datos vacios y haga la consulta:

```html
$codper=!empty ($_POST["codper"]) ? $_POST["codper"] : NULL;
$codcli    =!empty ($_POST["codcli"])     ? $_POST["codcli"]     : NULL;
$fromDate  =!empty ($_POST["from_date"])  ? $_POST["from_date"]  : NULL;
$toDate    =!empty ($_POST["to_date"])    ? $_POST["to_date"]    : NULL;

 //filter.php  
 if(isset($_POST["codper"], $_POST["codcli"], $_POST["from_date"], $_POST["to_date"]))  
 {  
      $connecttwo = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "Tr4ff1cfouraM!by?", "4am_traficon");
      $connecttwo->set_charset("utf8");
      $output = '';  
      $sql  = "SELECT * FROM ts_horas
      WHERE codclt = '$codcli' 
          AND coduser = '$codper' 
          AND fecha BETWEEN '$fromDate' AND '$toDate'
      ORDER BY fecha DESC";
```

el problema que veo es que ahora que agregue esa opcion de multiples datos en el **select** mis datos se envian como en varios Arrary y no se como solucionar eso y enviar los datos correctamente adjunto una cptura de cuando me funcionaba bien la consulta sin el **SELECT**
[image: Antes]

Ahora que agregue la opción **MULTIPLE** me envia los datos de esta manera y creo que ese es el problema ya intente unas cosas pero no se como resolver esto:
[image: Datos]

Answer (score 0):

Prueba cambiar el WHERE por:

```
WHERE codclt IN (".implode(',', array_map( function( $e ) { return "'$e'"; }, $codcli ) ).")
```